# Async support for functions that return an unchainable Promise<void>

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, promise

We are testing a call to a function that returns a `Promise<void>`. How can we wait until the promise resolves and `then` do some test?

The standard approach of `then()` off of the function does not work, because a `Promise<void>` is not thenable. So we have resorted to the following, which works but seems non-ideal.

Initial Approach

```
it("it does something...", function (done) {

    function wrappedPromise() {
        functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid(someArg);
        return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());
    }

    wrappedPromise()
        .then(() => {
            expect(someVar).toBe("someValue");
            done();
        });
});
```

Subsequent Approach

```
let wrapVoidPromise = (wrapped): Promise<any> => new Promise((resolve) => {
    wrapped();
    resolve();
});

it("it does something...", function (done) {

    wrapVoidPromise(() => functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid(someArg))
        .then(() => {
            expect(someVar).toBe("someValue");
            done();
        });
});
```

How can we do this without needing to wrap the unchainable promise?

## Edits

Here is a [GitHub link to the actual test](https://github.com/shaunluttin/openiddict-samples/blob/60ddd693271abd1857745635f554d8dde2aeb969/samples/ImplicitFlow/AureliaOidcClientJs/test/unit/open-id/open-id-router-configuration-service.spec.ts#L48-L57). It includes this call:

```
route.navigationStrategy(instruction) // returns Promise<void>
```

Here is a [GitHub link to the function](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/e3a0fa3310616e79c7850b563824d6f2f59ac581/src/interfaces.js#L27-L32). The implementation is buried somewhere inside the source to aurelia-router. Here is its interface:

```
navigationStrategy?: (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => Promise<void>|void;
```

Comment: `a Promise<void> is not thenable` - doesn't sound like a standard Promise in that case ... being thenable is the [core functionality of a Promise](https://promisesaplus.com/) - without `then` - it's pointless - what other purpose is there of such a Promise?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what `Promise<void>` means. It just means that the promise is resolved with no value (or the value `undefined`, if you prefer to think of it that way). It is a normal, chainable promise. Unless the promise library you are using is strange and not A+ compliant?

Comment: Do either of those comments suggest a way to run the tests after the promise resolves, without needing to wrap the promise? For whatever reason, @GregL, doing a `then()` on a `Promise<void>` is not working.

Comment: What promise library are you using? Or is this using the native `Promise`? And what version of jasmine?

Comment: @GregL It's TypeScript... I've updated the tags.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin that means you're using the native JavaScript Promise. TypeScript simply compiles to JavaScript in the end.... Do you have an example of `functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I added a link to the interface of the `functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid`.

Comment: [A Promise<void> is simply a Promise that resolves to undefined. Try this Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20wrapVoidPromise%20%3D%20(wrapped)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%3D%3E%20new%20Promise((resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20wrapped()%3B%20resolve()%3B%20%7D)%3B%0Alet%20functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid%20%3D%20(someArg)%3A%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20Promise.resolve(undefined)%3B%20%7D%0Alet%20someArg%20%3D%201%3B%0AwrapVoidPromise(()%20%3D%3E%20functionThatReturnsPromiseVoid(someArg)).then(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log('complete')%3B%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: Reference for the *Promise<void>* statement above (the URL took up most of the comment length): https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8516

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Can we `then()` a `Promise<void>` without needing to wrap it? Note: the playground does not recognize the `Promise` type.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to then it without a wrap. If you Run the code in the Playground, it logs correctly, as long as you're using a browser that supports Promises natively.

Answer (score 0):

You may try changing wrapUnchainedPromise as below :

```
function wrapUnchainedPromise(): Promise<any> {
      return route.navigationStrategy(instruction);     
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work, because `Promise<void>` is not assignable to `Promise<any>`.